# How to comment out a particular kind of boxes

Tags: tcolorbox

I have three boxes created with `\newtcolorbox` command. Let’s consider the first as **Red**, the second as **Green** and the last as **Blue**. How could I generate a pdf file containing only one kind (or more, regarding to my needs) of boxes?
Actually I tried to use some counter with a unique value to make difference between all the three kinds (e.g. the red counter value is **1** for all the **red** boxes). I am unable to go ahead further.

Comment: I think you should change the question title because I understand that you don't want to "generate a particular kind of boxes" because you already generated them and you want to print or not print some kind of boxes filtered by a color condition.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. How could I fix it? I cannot find any editing options.

Comment: I've changed the title to my taste. Hope it's better now. Just let me now if you prefer another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`comment` package can help you to filter which boxes suppress or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{red}{
notitle,
colback=red!30
}

\newtcolorbox{blue}{
notitle,
colback=blue!30
}

\newtcolorbox{green}{
notitle,
colback=green!30
}

%%%%%%
% Uncomment boxes to be suppressed
%%%%%%
\excludecomment{red}\let\endred\relax
%\excludecomment{green}\let\endgreen\relax
%\excludecomment{blue}\let\endblue\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{red}
Red
\end{red}
\begin{green}
Green
\end{green}
\begin{blue}
Blue
\end{blue}
\end{document}
```

Previous code should produce three boxes (red, green, blue) but commands

```
\excludecomment{red}
\let\endred\relax
```

in preamble convert all `red` boxes into comments which are not shown in results.

[image]

Comment: You can do with this proposal even more than what I requested: it offers flexibility and so you can en/disable boxes for a portion of the document. @Christian’s proposal is flexible too. But referring to the `comment` package documentation, there is no need to use `\let\endred\relax`. I checked if it was omitted, we got a compilation error. But I did not understand how the `\let` command fixed the error?

Comment: @ALOUI Sometime ago I had the same problem and someone else provide this solution with `\let\endred\relax`. What I more or less understant is that all environments are converted from `\begin{name}` and `\end{name}` to `\beginname` (or just `name` I'm not sure) and `\endname`. Therefore, `comment` can start working with `\begin{name}`   but later on doesn't understand `\end{name}` because previous `\begin` has been commented. And `\let\endname\relax` converts `\endname` command into nothing to do. I don't know how much sense have all of this, but It's my best answer.